# Not add data in variabli in the forin loop

Tags: powershell

i try parse log but have some trouble with *forin* loop.
E_ERROR variable clear after loop end, but W_ERROR var content data.
What i do wrong?

```bsh
$PATH = "C:\inlogs"
$LOGFILES = Get-ChildItem -Include @("*.log") -Path $PATH -Recurse;
$WORKFOLDER = "C:\outlogs"
$E_ERROR = ""
$W_ERROR = ""
foreach ($LOGFILE in $LOGFILES) {
    $LOGNAME = $LOGFILE.Name
    Write-Host $LOGFILE 
    $ELOGPATH = $WORKFOLDER + "\" + $LOGFILE.Name + ".E.log"
    $WLOGPATH = $WORKFOLDER + "\" + $LOGFILE.Name + ".W.log"

    foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($LOGFILE)) {
        if($line -match ',"Error",'){
            $E_ERROR += $line + "`r`n"
        } elseif ($line -match ',"Warning",') {
            $W_ERROR += $line + "`r`n"
        }    
    }
}
Out-File -FilePath $ELOGPATH -InputObject $EERROR -Encoding UTF8
Out-File -FilePath $WLOGPATH -InputObject $WERROR -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: You clear the  variables in the outer foreach, proper indenting would help to avoid such mistakes. Move the `Out-File` command inside that foreach (before the last curly brackets)

Comment: if i print $line inside first if section i see correct data. but if i print $E_ERROR outside if/elseif section i can't see any data, and $W_ERROR print propertly.

Comment: And i try use global: tag for variable. but this cant help.

Comment: Your comments don't make sense to me, you ***are*** aware that the variables are spelled differently in the Out-File commands - without underscore?

Comment: Out-File work propertly, $EERROR variable dont have any data. and as result i have clear log file in first time. but next Out-File with $WERROR write correct data to file. problem above, for unknown reason $EERROR variable don save content outside fist if{} construction. but in next elseif{} section i dont have this error and $W_ERROR variable save data ouside forech(){} construction.

Comment: if I put Out-File inside the foreach, I will get many log files, but I need only one summary log file

Comment: So why do you reset the variables and also name the files per processed LogFile? If you want one overall  Warning/Error log file that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version should work as expected, it also

- uses Join-Path to build the log file names
- avoids the double extension `.log.E.log`

```bsh
$PATH = "C:\inlogs"
$LOGFILES = Get-ChildItem -Include @("*.log") -Path $PATH -Recurse;
$WORKFOLDER = "C:\outlogs"

foreach ($LOGFILE in $LOGFILES) {
    $LOGNAME = $LOGFILE.BaseName
    Write-Host $LOGFILE 
    $ELOGPATH = Join-Path $WORKFOLDER ($LOGName+'.E.log')
    $WLOGPATH = Join-Path $WORKFOLDER ($LOGName+'.W.log')
    $E_ERROR = ""
    $W_ERROR = ""
    foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($LOGFILE)) {
        if($line -match ',"Error",'){
            $E_ERROR += $line + "`r`n"
        } elseif ($line -match ',"Warning",') {
            $W_ERROR += $line + "`r`n"
        }    
    }
    Out-File -FilePath $ELOGPATH -InputObject $E_ERROR -Encoding UTF8
    Out-File -FilePath $WLOGPATH -InputObject $W_ERROR -Encoding UTF8
}
```